# Putting element into TreeMap Java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, treemap

I'm trying to use a TreeMap to store my data, but i have a problem to add new element into it.

```
public class Graph {

private TreeMap<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> tree;

public Graph() {
    this.tree = new TreeMap<>();
}

public void addVertex(int label) {
    this.tree.put(new Vertex(label), new ArrayList<Vertex>());
}
```

When I use my addVertex method, I don't have error but when I display my map, I only have 1 element into my treemap : {1=[]}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Graph g = new Graph();


  g.addVertex(1);
  g.addVertex(2);
  g.addVertex(3);
  g.addVertex(4);
```

I tryed to create a basic map like that :

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
  map.put(1, "dog");
  map.put(2, "cat");

  System.out.println(map);
```

And it works, so I really don't understand my mistake.
I also check if my class Vertex was correct, and it is working well.

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {

private int label;

public Vertex(int label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.label + "";
}

public int compareTo(Vertex o) {
    return this.label == o.label ? 1 : 0;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;

    if( ! (obj instanceof Vertex) ) return false;

    Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;

    return this.label == other.label;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return label < 0 ? 0 : label;
}
```

}

I edited my Vertex class and addded `hashcode()` and `equals()` but it still doesn't work.

Can you help me to find my mistake please ?
Thanks by advance !

Comment: `I also check if my class Vertex was correct` - if it was correct, you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: What does your `Vertex` class look like? What does its `compareTo` method look like? Also, did you implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Comment: I added it in my post check it, and no I didn't implements equals() and hashCode()

Comment: @yayademil: out of curiosity: why don't you just return `label` in `hashCode`? Why filter out negative values? It's not *wrong* per se, and definitely doesn't affect this question, but I don't see an advantage to do this.

Comment: @JoachimSauer honestly I don't really understand what is the role of hashCode() so I think my hashCode() is wrong. I will follow your tips and change it !

Comment: @yayademil: Fair enough, they are not trivial concepts (and I won't attempt to explain them in the comments here, feel free to google, there are plenty of good explanations out there).

Comment: `equals()` and `hashCode()` do not come into the picture when dealing with TreeMap

Answer (score 1):

Your `compareTo` method is wrong. Take a look at [its specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)):

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.

Since you only ever return the values 1 and 0, this condition can not hold.

In general a comparable must always support all three cases:

- this is less than the argument: return a negative integer (usually `-1`)
- this is sorted the same as the argument: return 0
- this is greater than the argument: return a positive integer (usually `1`)

If your code doesn't have those three cases, it can't be correct.

Since you basically want to sort according to `label`, the simplest implementation would be to delegate to `Integer.compare`:

```
public int compareTo(Vertex o) {
    return Integer.compare(this.label, o.label);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! It's working now, I changed my compareTo() method ! Can I delete my hashCode() and my equals methods then ?

Comment: @yayademil: I don't think they are required if you only use `TreeMap`, so you could get rid of them.

Comment: @yayademil I wouldn't bother deleting them, in case you decide in future to use HashMap instead of TreeMap.

Comment: Oh ok, so in my case i can delete it then, because I don't have to compare my Vertex with each other. Thanks guys !